# Post values are not set because of special characters in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to make a post to my web api service. The point is that while sending a message like

```
{ message: "it is done" }
```

working fine. However when I  use special characters like çıöpş in my message it is unable to convert my json so that the post object remains null. What can I do? It is either current culture issue or something else. I tried to send my post parameter as HtmlEncoded style with encoding HttpUtility class but it didn't work either.

```
public class Animal{

  public string Message {get;set;}
}
```

Web API method

```
public void DoSomething(Animal a){

}
```

Client

```
Animal a = new Animal();
a.Message = "öçşistltl";
string postDataString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);        
string URL = "http://localhost/Values/DoSomething";
WebClient client = new WebClient();

client.UploadStringCompleted += client_UploadStringCompleted;
client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(URL), "POST",postDataString);
```

Best regards,

Kemal

Comment: Please show your code. The one that sends the request to your Web API most importantly. Also your Web API action could help. How can you possibly expect us telling you why your code doesn't work without showing it? It's ridiculous.

Comment: I editted my comment,  hope this helps.

Comment: Have you tried `client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;` ?

Comment: Use fiddler to look at the actual message being posted. And update your post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility is to use the [UploadDataAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144226.aspx) method which allows you to specify UTF-8 when encoding the data because the `UploadStringAsync` method that you are using basically uses `Encoding.Default` to encode the data when writing it to the socket. So if your system is configured to use some other encoding than UTF-8 you get into trouble because `UploadStringAsync` uses your system encoding whereas in your content type header you have specified `charset=utf-8` which could be conflicting.

With the `UploadDataAsync` method you could be more explicit in your intents:

```
Animal a = new Animal();
a.Message = "öçşistltl";
string postDataString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);        
string URL = "http://localhost/Values/DoSomething";
string postDataString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.UploadDataCompleted += client_UploadDataCompleted;
    client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    client.UploadDataAsync(new Uri(URI), "POST", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postDataString));
}
```

---

Another possibility is to specify the encoding of the client and use `UploadStringAsync`:

```
Animal a = new Animal();
a.Message = "öçşistltl";
string postDataString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);        
string URL = "http://localhost/Values/DoSomething";
string postDataString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    client.UploadStringCompleted += client_UploadStringCompleted;
    client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    client.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(URI), "POST", postDataString);
}
```

---

Or if you install the [`Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client`](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.client) NuGet package on the client you could directly use the new `HttpClient` class (which is the new kid on the block) to consume your WebAPI instead of `WebClient`:

```
Animal a = new Animal();
a.Message = "öçşistltl";
var URI = "http://localhost/Values/DoSomething";
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client
        .PostAsync<Animal>(URI, a, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
        .ContinueWith(x => x.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ContinueWith(y =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(y.Result);
        }))
        .Wait();
}
```

Comment: Is JsonConvert defined in an open source assembly?  I googled and I found some Newtonsoft.Json assembly.  Or is JsonConvert defined in an assembly provided by Microsoft?

Comment: It's part of the open source Newtonsoft.Json package that Microsoft is distributing along with the Web API now.