# Passing json data to a WebApi with special characters

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am facing an issue.

I have a string value that i pass to `web api` controller.

If i pass `"myValue"` , it received as as `"myValue"` in controller but if i pass `"&&myValue"` than it is received as `null`.

Any idea about it?

**Code:**

Web Client

```
factory.downloadStrudentReport = function(date, Name) {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('dowload', _url + 'GetStudentPdfReport', { date: date, Nanme: Name});
};
```

Server

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetStudentPdfReport")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetStudentPdfReport(DateTime date, string stuName)
}

 //////////////
{
```

Another post, 
[Passing json data to a WebApi with special characters results to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760824/passing-json-data-to-a-webapi-with-special-characters-results-to-null)

says, `client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;` but not sure where?
Any idea?

Comment: Show us your code please.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) function to encode the values.