# How to post a long dash(—) as part of string data in a http post request to Web API

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-web-api

I have a requirement where I have been posting data to a web API as a json string in a POST request and the post method retrieves the data from the body. This works perfectly for most data, but it does not work when I include a long dash(—) as part of the data in any fields.

I have a Email class with some string fields and I am passing it to the API to save in the database.
Here is how I am implementing the call:

```
    public string PostNewEmailRecord(string APIEndpoint, CampaignWave Email)
    {
        string StrEmailId = string.Empty;
        _endpoint = APIEndpoint;

        try
        {
            string strData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Email);
            _client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");
            _client.UploadString(APIEndpoint, _requestType, strData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return StrEmailId;
    }
```

And here is the post method of Web API:

```
    public void Post([FromBody]CampaignWave email)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
            {
                CampaignWaveRepository cr = new CampaignWaveRepository();
                object objReturnValue = cr.Insert(email);
                transaction.Complete();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }
```

When I include a dash the API post method receives a null value as email.

Please help me how I can successfully pass the '—' without any issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What received on webAPI endpoint? you need to check how objects are deserialized on server. Are properties containing 'long dash' strings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing json data to a WebApi with special characters results to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760824/passing-json-data-to-a-webapi-with-special-characters-results-to-null)

Comment: Its probably client encoding =>  you need to set up `client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;`

Comment: Thank you @Pribina It worked like a charm.

Comment: i posted it as and answer. so you can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments it could be caused by encoding:

`client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8`