# Asp.NetCore API Controller not getting Data from Json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-webapi

I have 2 applications, one which posts data to another. When I run the first application the post method in the controller executes but the model or ObjavaDto (objaveList) can't be found so it's null. When I copy-paste the json from var json into Postman everything works. What am I missing?

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objaveList[2]);
```

I used [2] just for simplicity reasons because there are a lot of them

```
string url = "http://localhost:61837/api/Objave";

string result;
using (var client = new WebClient())
      {
         client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
         result = client.UploadString(url, "POST", json);
      }
```

2nd application Controller

```
namespace StecajeviInfo.Controllers.Api
{
     [Route("api/[controller]")]
     public class ObjaveController : Controller
     {  

       [HttpPost]
       public void Post([FromBody]ObjavaDto objaveList)
       {

       } 

     }
}
public class ObjavaDto
{
    public string OznakaSpisa { get; set; }
    public string NazivOtpravka { get; set; }
    public string NazivStecajnogDuznika { get; set; }
    public string PrebivalisteStecajnogDuznika { get; set; }
    public string SjedisteStecajnogDuznika { get; set; }
    public string OIBStecajnogDuznika { get; set; }
    public string OglasSeOdnosiNa { get; set; }
    public DateTime DatumObjave { get; set; }
    public string OibPrimatelja { get; set; }
    public string Dokument { get; set; }
}
```

Sent data looks like this

```
{
    "OznakaSpisa":"St-6721/2015",
    "NazivOtpravka":"Rješenje - otvaranje stečajnog postupka St-6721/2015-7",
    "NazivStecajnogDuznika":"RAIN AIR d.o.o.",
    "PrebivalisteStecajnogDuznika":"Savska 144/A, 10000, Zagreb",
    "SjedisteStecajnogDuznika":"",
    "OIBStecajnogDuznika":‌​"37144498637",
    "Oglas‌​SeOdnosiNa":"Missing Oib",
    "DatumObjave":"\/Date(1501106400000)\/",
    "OibPrimatelja"‌​:"37144498637",
    "Doku‌​ment":"e-oglasna.pra‌​vosudje.hr/sites/def‌​ault/files/ts-zg-st/‌​…;"
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to send the entire list or just the one? also show the JSON data string sent over the wire.

Comment: I can't style it so i didn't post it

Comment: My goal is to send a whole list but I changed the Dto from ObjaveListDto to Objave Dto  so i can downscale the problem

Comment: No you need to show exacty what you want and tried. sending a list is completely different to sending a single item. Provide exactly what you tried as a [mcve] so that it can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: The date property might be the reason. Try removing it and see if it works. If it works, then de date should be formatted differently. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/the-right-json-date-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your replies, you have been very helpful and gave me an idea how to test. I tested with commenting out properties and I found out it's because of the special characters in Naziv otpravka ("Rješenje" and "stečajnog") which are luckily present only in that property.

I found that this solved the problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/12081747/6231007

```
client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
client.UploadDataAsync(new Uri(url), "POST", 
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
```

Answer (score 0):

Datetime is problematic. Make it nullable (DateTime?) and test with that. You'll probably get all other properties filled and datetime will stay null. If that's the problem, make sure your client sends datetime format that your model binder understands.